# React - Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

So I'm trying to convert my React 2 app to React 4. The first thing I'm doing is working on the new React router, but I'm having a number of issues. The one I'm posting about is getting the Link component to work. When add the Link component in my Layout.js, i get the following error(see below). If i remove the Link component the error goes away. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import About from "./components/About";
import NotFound from "./components/Layout";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Layout} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
const app = document.getElementById('app');

render(<Layout />, app);
```

Layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>
            Layout
          </h1>
            <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

About.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h2> 
            About
        </h2>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-tutorials",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "history": "3.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot", 
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
    at Link.render (Link.js:76)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:587)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:607)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:220)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:241)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (ReactDOMComponent.js:591)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:479)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing BrowserRouter and Link from react-router, but they need to be imported from react-router-dom.  You should really review the [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) on their docs because it isn't necessarily a straightforward merge from react-router 2 to 4.  You're going to run into other problems since you're relying on Match and Miss.

You're going to need to make the following change to app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import About from "./components/About";
import NotFound from "./components/Layout";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Layout} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
const app = document.getElementById('app');

render(<App />, app);
```

...and the following changes to Layout.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>
            Layout
          </h1>
            <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your mistakes could have been caught if you were using a linter, like ESLint.  I highly recommend looking into that.

Comment: @John Is it possible that your component isn't being rendered within a router?  What routing are you using?

Comment: Everything you see is everything i got

Comment: You're also importing BrowserRouter from the wrong spot.  Take a look at the [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) They also need to be imported from react-router-dom

Comment: @John Take a look at the updated answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried entering your code, but i still cant get it to work. See updated answer.

Comment: @John you're rendering the wrong component.  You need to render App, not Layout.  When you render layout, you're rending a Link component outside of the router's context.  See updated answer (especially the note about ESLint!  It is very helpful.)

Comment: Yeah, now i get a list of new error, man angular routing is so so so much better. Thanks buddy, at least the pages display now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in version 4 you have to import Link from react-router-dom

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Additional docs:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: FYI, according to react-router, they use react-router. http://frontend.turing.io/lessons/react-router-4.html

Comment: @John, sorry to say but that is incorrect. The tutorial must have old syntax, this is pulled straight from react-routers docs itself, which say to import from react-router-dom https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: Well, i thought they don't use history anymore? Why would i be getting that new error?